# How to change "State/Province" field from text to dropdown list in checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I am looking for a solution where i can change the "State/Province" field to show as a dropdown list in shipping section of a checkout page in my website. The default country is set to AU (Australia) for store. Although i have added the states of the target country (AU) in the table "directory_country_region".

I have set the country "Australia" in **State is Required for** in **state options** in stores > configuration > general.
But no change appears even after clearing the cache. I am struggling with this issue for many hours. Any help to fix it would be just great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Run Below SQL Query to Add Australian States Dropdown in Magento 2:**

```
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) VALUES ('AU', 'ACT', 'Australian Capital Territory');
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) VALUES ('AU', 'NSW', 'New South Wales');
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) VALUES ('AU', 'VIC', 'Victoria');
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) VALUES ('AU', 'QLD', 'Queensland');
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) VALUES ('AU', 'SA', 'South Australia');
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) VALUES ('AU', 'WA', 'Western Australia');
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) VALUES ('AU', 'TAS', 'Tasmania');
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) VALUES ('AU', 'NT', 'Northern Territory');
```

And then Run Below Query:

```
INSERT INTO directory_country_region_name( locale, region_id, name )
SELECT 'en_US' AS "language", region_id, default_name
FROM `directory_country_region`
WHERE country_id = 'AU';
```

Once the above SQL script is run correctly, Australian states dropdown is shown while the selection of Australia as the country. You can make use of this SQL script anywhere to add Australian states dropdown in Magento 2.

Comment: Already some customers are registerd while state as textbox, If i change state/Province as Dropdown .Does already registered customer's state/Province value chang according to textbox vlaue?